# GeoJSON layer not showing up on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I'm struggling with making my GeoJSON points to show up on leaflet map.

The codes for the javascript where I tried to add in the GeoJSON:

```
        var coniferous = L.layerGroup();

        var geojsondata = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("treedata2.geojson", {
        pointToLayer: function(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {return L.marker(latlng);}}).addTo(coniferous);
```

I have already referenced the ajax plugin in the head section of the html file

```
    <script src="leaflet.ajax.js"></script>
```

The GeoJSON file code is as follow

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Significant Trees",
"features": [
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-79.484593, 43.696533, 0.0]}, "properties": {"What_is_the_species_name": "Maple"}},
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-79.433099, 43.846487, 0.0]}, "properties": {"What_is_the_species_name": "Pine"}}
]
}
```

I have also tried to coordsToLatLng but it doesn't seem to be the problem as the markers don't still show up at all, not even in the wrong locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the LayerGroup to the map: `var coniferous = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);`